# Animating CSS-Only Hamburger Menu Icon on hover not on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope someone can help me with this.

I want to use one of the Hamburger Icon transitions from http://callmenick.com/post/animating-css-only-hamburger-menu-icons

The jquery for the Icon transition is triggered on `.click` event. I would like it to trigger on hover or `mouseover` and out so the animation is played on hover and reversed when the mouse is out.

Here is the script that needs to be changed.

```
    // Animated Hamburger Icon
    (function() {

    "use strict";

    var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".c-hamburger");

    for (var i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var toggle = toggles[i];
      toggleHandler(toggle);
    };

    function toggleHandler(toggle) {
      toggle.addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("is-active") : this.classList.add("is-active");
      });
    }

  })();
```

Comment: keep in mind that mobile users don't have hover events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using jQuery you could use `hover()` event with `toggleClass()` method :

```
function toggleHandler(toggle) {
     $( toggle ).hover(function(){
         $(this).toggleClass("is-active");
     });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do smth like this

```
      (function() {

            "use strict";

            var toggles = document.querySelectorAll(".c-hamburger");

            for (var i = toggles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
              var toggle = toggles[i];
              toggleHandler(toggle);
            };

            function toggleHandler(toggle) {
                toggle.addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    (this.classList.contains("is-active") === true) ? this.classList.remove("is-active") : this.classList.add("is-active");
                });
                toggle.addEventListener( "mouseover", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    this.classList.add("is-active");
                })
                toggle.addEventListener( "mouseout", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    this.classList.remove("is-active");
                })         
            }

        })();
```

Comment: hi christoz, that is exactly what I was looking for. thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure, please upvote the answer cause i need xp to have access to stackoverflow chatrooms.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover

In the example provided, look at line 24.

You can just replace 'click' with 'mouseover', it will behave the way you want.

Comment: I've tried that and it works half way. it triggers the animation i need to trigger   the mouseout too, otherwise the animation will not be reversed.

Comment: Have you tried in addition using .mouseleave(); to trigger the original styling to the burger?

Comment: Hi Julian, thank you for your help. Since I dont know jquery at all i have not tried .mouseleave(); but Christoz just posted the solution I was looking for.